# C# : Split a sequence of numbers after given parameter length

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have a number something like this :
12345668788451223356456898941220036696897894

Now, the question is how can I split the number after each 8 digits.That is,
I need the output as :
12345668

78845122 and so on up to the end of the number.
If I convert it to string, I don't have a method so that I could split it only with length parameter.

Thanks in advance for answering.

Comment: Which .NET version are you using? Right now it looks like you just took every c# tag which was available...

Comment: I'm curious, which numeric datatype do you use to store that number?

Comment: I store that to array and then convert to string @Steve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**String approach**

> If I convert it to string, I don't have a method so that I could split it only with length parameter.

Well you have `Substring`, don't you? You could use LINQ:

```
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, bigNumber.Length / 8)
                        .Select(x => bigNumber.Substring(x * 8, 8)
                        .ToList();
```

or a straight loop:

```
var numbers = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < bigNumber.Length / 8; i++)
{
    numbers.Add(bigNumber.Substring(i * 8, 8);
}
```

If you need to end up with a `List<int>` instead, just add a call to `int.Parse` in there.

(You should check that the input string length is a multiple of 8 first.)

**BigInteger approach**

It's not clear what form you have this number in to start with. If it's a `BigInteger`, you could keep using [`DivRem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.divrem.aspx):

```
BigInteger value = ...;
List<BigInteger> results = new List<BigInteger>();
BigInteger divisor = 100000000L;
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    BigInteger tmp;
    value = BigInteger.DivRem(value, divisor, out tmp);
    results.Add(tmp);
}
```

Note that I'm using `count` here rather than just looping until `value` is 0, in case you have lots of leading 0s. You need to know how many numbers you're trying to extract :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer again..But,how long did u think for answering this question ? As I am still a beginner I wonder how u got the answer so quick :)

Comment: Instead of 'x' in numbers.Add(bigNumber.Substring(x * 8, 8) in straight loop, there should be 'i'.....

Comment: @Indish: **Jon Skeet** is an author of a C# book.

Comment: @Indish: [this might be relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all).

Comment: @Indish Jon has the answer before you even asked the question :) [Jon Skeet Facts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9134/182513)

Answer (score 2):

Use this regex to split after each 8 digits,

```
\d{1,8}
```

OR

```
(\d{1,8})
```

### Output:

```
12345668
78845122
33564568
98941220
03669689
7894
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
string string.substring(int startIndex,int length)
```

In you case, you can write a loop to extract the 8 digits from the string till all the numbers are extracted

```
string sDigits = "12345668788451223356456898941220036696897894";
int iArrLen = sDigits.length / 8;
string[] sArrDigitList = new string[iArrLen];

for(int i=0; i < sDigits.length; i++)
{
   sArrDigitList[i] = sDigits.substring(0, 8);
   sDigits = sDigits.substring(sDigits.length-8);
}
```